# excel vba copy multiple columns to another sheet to one column

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in copying multiple columns from one sheet to another sheet in one column. Below is an example. 
Thanks!

```
Adam      Sammy        Roy
111       444          777
222       555          888
333       666          999


Adam
111
222
333
Sammy
444
555
666
Roy
777
888
999
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Start by posting the code you have. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with these codes I guess.

```
Sub one_column()
Dim numCol As Integer
numCol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
For i = 1 To numCol
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, i), Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, i)).Copy
    firstBlank = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
    If firstBlank = 1 Then
    Sheet2.Cells(firstBlank, 1).PasteSpecial
    Else
    Sheet2.Cells(firstBlank + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End If

Next

End Sub
```